# Grinder 3 - Logging aggregate results to a file

Tags: testing, load-testing, grinder

The grinder 3 shows aggregate results in the GUI console.
Is there a way to get these results in a log-file.

I would like to be able to start a console automatically and then load it's graphs in excel.

I do not mean that I want the stats from each agent's log-file, but rather that I want the aggregate stats displayed in the console.

The "save results" in the menu does not do the job, since it only stores the results at a given moment in time. The graph that I want is dynamic

I would like to be able to recreate this graph later in excel via csv:
[image: Grinder Statistics]

Comment: Take a look at the console's REST API, it may allow you to save off the aggregate results on demand.

Comment: the rest api allows me to poll aggregate data. Which does give me a csv. But the data is still aggregate. Simillar to the data in the table, whereas I want the data in the graph.

Comment: You may have to maintain your own state for this; i.e. keeping track of the last n samples.  Or your could explore alternate approaches like post-processing the log files w/ Grinder Analyzer, or adding the Grinder data to Graphite in realtime with the Grinder Logster parser.